# ARMA(2,1) autocovariance functions

Tags: self-study, arma

I have an ARMA(1,2) model:

$$x_t = 0.6 x_{t-1} + u_t + 0.1 u_{t-1} - 0.2 u_{t-2} + 5$$

and I figured out the

($\delta$ = autocovariance functions)

$\delta(0)= \beta_1\delta(1) + \alpha_1\delta_{ux}(-1)+\alpha_2\delta_{ux}(-2)$

$\delta(1)= \beta_1\delta(0)+\alpha_1\delta_{ux}(0) +\alpha_2\delta_{ux}(-1)$

$\delta(2)= \beta_1\delta(1)+\alpha_2\delta_{ux}(0)$

But now I am dealing with an ARMA(2,1) and I am confused with regards to how to formulate their equations:

$$x_t = 0.7 x_{t-1} -0.1 x_{t-2}+ u_t + 0.1 u_{t-1} + 5$$